# Create button and launch function via it

Tags: javascript, button

All should be easy, but it doesn't work for me for some reason, please help!

```
TYPER.prototype = {
  init: function () {
    this.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')

    this.canvas.style.width = this.WIDTH + 'px'
    this.canvas.style.height = this.HEIGHT + 'px'

    this.canvas.width = this.WIDTH * 2
    this.canvas.height = this.HEIGHT * 2

    let button = document.createElement("button")
    button.innerHTML = "Start!!!"

    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
    body.appendChild(button);

    button.addEventListener ("click", this.startPage())


  },...
  startPage: function () {
     button.style.display = "block"
    this.loadWords()
   },
```

I am trying to create a button on page when page launches. After pressing that button function should start. Doesn't work for me. As I understood, browser does nothing when button is pressed, tried alert it - nothing happened.

Comment: This `.addEventListener ("click", this.startPage())` should be `addEventListener ("click", this.startPage)`. Also, since you are using `this` reference in handler, you will have to do this: `this.startPage.bind(this)` before

Comment: @Rajesh Tried to do it that way - still nothing happens :(

Comment: just saw, `button` is not available in `startPage`'s scope. You still have to create/fetch it again

Comment: @SergeiFrolov - There are multiple issues with the code.  I posted an answer that takes my best guess at the core issue.  However, please follow the advice and let us know if you have further questions updating your question as advised.  Until you make those updates your question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!  You should create runnable examples.  This makes it easier to help you out.  Also remove the non-relevant code.  I took a shot at helping you do this by making some assumptions.

The main problem I see here is that you are actually **calling** a function instead of **passing** a function.  It looks like you are using ES6 style.  I dropped back to ES5 style just cause it's another layer of complexity that doesn't appear to be necessary for this issue.

```js
let button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Start!!!";

let body = document.body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener("click", startPage);//Pass a function.  Not make a function call

function startPage() {
  button.style.display = "block"
  loadWords();
};
    
function loadWords() {
  console.log('loadWords called');
};
```